# This code is getting dumped and showing segmentation failure. I can't fix it

Tags: c++, c++17

This code is getting dumped and showing a segmentation failure. How can I fix it? How can I solve this error?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int a[] = {4, 3, 2, 1, 5};
    int temp,i,j;
    for ( i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; i < 5; j++)
        {
            if (a[j] > a[i])
            {
                temp = a[i];
                a[i] = a[j];
                a[j] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        cout << a[i];
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your inner loop is checking against i instead of j.

Answer (score 2):

I think you meant to type `for (j = 0; j < 5; j++)`. Otherwise `j` will just increment until the loop commits an out-of-bounds operation.

Comment: Thank you. That was a bad mistake. I should have been more careful.

Comment: Damn. Reminds me of this: ib.paths.ws/EjHqOp8O